# dynamically pass parameter in js inside dynamically created <div>

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have this script which dynamically creates divs. I would like to pass parameters to the controller and be able to visualize the booking form after clicking Book button.
With thymeleaf I would do it like this   th:href="@{/hotels/{id}/booking-form(id=*{id})}" however I am not really sure how can I use thymeleaf inside this dynamically created div.

So I tried with javascript, but of course, it is not working so I would really appreciate if someone tells me what I am doing wrong and how can I get the id and pass it to the controller.

```
                    <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">

                    document.getElementById('showAll').addEventListener('click', showAll);


                    function showAll() {
                        fetch('http://localhost:8080/accommodations')
                            .then(response => {
                                return response.json()
                            })
                            .then((data) => {
                                let output = `<h2> Search Results </h2>`;
                                data.forEach(function (hotel) {
                                    output += `
                                /some divs here/
                             
                                      <!-- Book Now button -->
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mt-1">
                                        <div class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" id="bookingBtn" data-hotel-id="' + hotel.id + '" >Book Now</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>`;
                                });
                                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
                            })
                    }

                    function booking() {
                        let hotelId = $(this).data('hotel-id')
                        fetch('http://localhost:8080/hotels/' + hotelId + '/booking-form', {
                            method: 'POST'
                        })
                    }

                    document.getElementById('bookingBtn').addEventListener('click', booking);


                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create a string you can include variables this way `${var}`. So in your case you should do `data-hotel-id="${hotel.id}"`

```
data.forEach(function(hotel) {
      output += `
         /some divs here/
                                 
         <!-- Book Now button -->
         <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mt-1">
           <div class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" id="bookingBtn" data-hotel-id="${hotel.id}" >Book Now</div>
           </div>
         </div>`;
    });
```

Comment: thank you, I tried your suggestion, but it is still not doing anything. Perhaps my mistake is somewhere else.

Comment: Did you check if the generated elements contain the data-hotel-id attribute? You could inspect your page to check this. Also check if the hotel contains the id value when you are iterating.

Comment: when iterating, each hotel has an id, but hotelId is undefined

Comment: Try to `console.log($(this))` inside your booking function to check if you have access to the element